# Proper way to handle Thread.interrupted() in a Callable?

Tags: java, multithreading, future, callable

What is the proper way to handle Thread.interrupted() in a Callable? I'm guessing that the callable should throw an InterruptedException; for example:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Object> {
    public Object call() {
        Object result = null;

        // Simulate long-running operation that calculates result
        while (true) {
            ...
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            }
        }

        result = ... // something produced by the long-running operation    

        return result;
    }
}
```

Is this correct, or is there a more appropriate way to handle it? Thanks.

Comment: The One True Source for explaining `InterruptedException` is [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html).

Comment: I read that earlier, but it doesn't mention Callable. Very good article, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**:

After some back and forth, it seems like you want to be able to interrupt your IO routines. This seems like a good job for some of the NIO `InterrutibleChannel` classes.  For example, reading from the following `BufferedReader` is interruptible and will throw `InterruptedIOException`.  See here for [more examples of the NIO code](http://www.forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html).

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    Channels.newInputStream((new FileInputStream(
        new File(...))).getChannel())));
```

Then, you can call `future.cancel()` which will interrupt your thread and cause the IO to throw a `InterruptedIOException`.  If that happens, you could *not* catch the `IOException` and let it trickle out of the `call()` method.

---

If you want to pass back to the `Future` that the `call()` method was interrupted then I think throwing `InterruptedException` is fine.  Another option would be to just `return null;` or some other marker object from your `call()` method instead.  That's typically what I do if a thread was interrupted.

One thing to remember is that if `call()` throws `InterruptedException`, when you do a `future.get()` it will throw a `ExecutionException` and the *cause* of that exception is going to be an `InterruptedException`.  Don't be confused that `future.get()` can also throw a `InterruptedException` itself if the `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` times out.

```
 try {
     result = future.get();
 } catch (ExecutionException e) {
     if (e.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
        // call() method was interrupted
     }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     // get was interrupted
 }
```

If, however, `future.cancel(true)` was called then the `future.get()` will throw a `CancellationException` instead.

Comment: I'll provide a little more context. My code doesn't actually use a while (true) loop - it is reading from a custom InputStream that checks the value of Thread.interrupted() in read(byte). The read() method throws InterruptedException to ensure that the calling code (which is reading from the stream) properly closes the stream.

Comment: Turns out that this won't work, since read() can only throw IOException. Looks like what I want might be InterruptedIOException.

Comment: Sure @Greg.  Another idea is to use an `InterruptibleChannel` that NIO supports.

Comment: I thought about using an InterruptibleChannel, but it wasn't immediately obvious how I might do that (my code uses standard java.io input/output streams).

Comment: Added some example code about how to use `InterruptibleChannel`s.  Looks pretty simple although I've never had to use it @GregBrown.

Comment: Looks reasonable, though it seems to be dependent on FileInputStream, whereas my code uses arbitrary InputStreams (and OutputStreams).

Comment: Yeah, streams are not interruptible @GregBrown so you are SOL there.

Comment: Just to close the loop - my final solution was to implement a custom InputStream class that wraps another InputStream and calls Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() in read(). If isInterrupted() returns true, the method throws an InterruptedIOException. Otherwise, it delegates the read() to the wrapped stream. It also delegates close() to the wrapped stream. I did the same for OutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

It depends actually on how you want the thread waiting on `get()`.  If you *do not* want the waiting thread to have an exception thrown then you do not want to `throw new InterruptedException`

Imagine

```
try{
  future.get();
}catch(ExecutionException ex){

}catch(InterruptedException em){

}
```

If any exception occurs what would you expect it to be?  In your case it is an `ExecutionException`.  If you do not want an `ExecutionException` then you should not rethrow the InterruptedException.

Comment: In this case, my callable is reading from an InputStream. I want ensure that the stream is closed if cancel() is called on the Future instance (see my comment on Gray's answer).

Comment: Do you ever `get` on the future?

Comment: Yes, eventually I will call get() on the Future (if the Future was not cancelled).

Comment: Ok, if the InterruptedException is ever thrown propogating outside of the `call` method, any subsequent `get` will see the InterruptedException, which in my opinion doesn't seem to fit for the waiting thread.  This also assumes the thread-pool thread will clean up the Callable's resources.  If the waiting thread will clean up the resources maybe getting the InterruptedException would make sense.

Comment: In this case, I believe any subsequent get() will throw a CancelledException, since the InterruptedException would have been thrown due to a call to Future#cancel(). So that seems like this should be OK - right?

Comment: The only problem with this assumption I see is if there is any other way for an InterruptedException to be thrown (ie. in the read method).  If that is not the case, then you are right you would see a `CancellationException`

Comment: No, as my answer shows, if `call()` throws `InterruptedException`, the `future.get()` throws `ExecutionException` and the cause is the `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @Gray If a cancel causes the the InterruptedException in which the Future is essentially cancelled it seems that a `CancellationException` is thrown before an `ExecutionException`

Comment: You're right @John.  I didn't realize that he was canceling the future as well.

Comment: Based on the Javadoc, it seems as though get() will throw a CancellationException if the future was terminated by a call to cancel() (which will trigger a call to interrupt() on the worker thread). However, if the worker thread is interrupted by some other means, I imagine an ExecutionException would be thrown (though I'm not sure how that might happen unless the callable interrupted itself).

Comment: @GregBrown You are correct with everything you wrote.  If the Thread cannot be interrupted for any other reason you are probably safe.